# How to collage display programmatically?

Tags: windows, screen, display

I know that I can collage display by **Intel® Graphics Control Panel** and **Intel® Graphics Command Center**.

However, can I collage display programmatically? Whatever the solution is Windows API, Intel API, Powershell, Command Line or any document.

Waiting for help, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexw) WinAPI. Set `DM_POSITION` bit in `dmFields`, and `dmPosition` to the value.

To find monitor device names, and current rectangles, `EnumDisplayMonitors` and `GetMonitorInfo`.

Couple more notes.

The primary display has top left position `[ 0, 0 ]` and you can’t change that. However, coordinates are signed integers, so you can set some other display position to negative X.

Beware of DPI scaling. The units you’ll be getting in the rectangles, and setting in the offsets, depend on DPI awareness manifest of your program.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried to use ChangeDisplaySettingsEx WinAPI but it didn't work. When I try to set dmPelsWidth with a value which is bigger than the single monitor supported, this WinAPI will return error. Now I am tring to use Intel CUI SDK, if I have any news I will tell you.

Comment: @Whitesoft Why are you trying to change size? The only thing you need to change is position.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different things? Collage display is a special display mode. If we enable collage display, we can only see one display in the Windows Control Panel. And all desktops will be merged into one. If you maximize the window, you will see that the window covers all displays, as if we only have one physical display. If you turn on this feature with two 1920 * 1080 monitors horizontally, you will find that the resolution becomes 3840 * 1080.

Comment: I wonder if there is a powershell option to implement these...